# How to cancel function using clearTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cleartimeout

How to cancel function using clearTimeout() when stay bottom page less than 4 sec.?

When stay at bottom page 4 sec, will alert, it's OK ^^

But when stay at bottom page less than 4 sec, then scroll to top page, Why it's will be alert too

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var height = $('#idpage').height();
    var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())){
        var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            alert("bottom");   
        }, 4000);
    }
    else{
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `timer` as a local variable so every time the `scroll` handler is called a new variable reference is used. Instead you need to preserve the value of the previous timer so you need to declare the variable outside the scope of the `scroll` handler like

```
var timer;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var height = $('#idpage').height();
    var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())) {
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            alert("bottom");
        }, 4000);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define timer variable on the top of scroll event.

```
var timer = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var height = $('#idpage').height();
    var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())){
        var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        }, 4000);
    }
    else{
        if ( timer) {
            console.log(timer);
             clearTimeout(timer);
        }


    }
});
```